# How do I control an oscillator's frequency with a sequencer

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'd like to know how to control an `AKOscillator`'s frequency using an `AKSequencer`, however the few examples([1](http://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Sequencer%20-%20Single%20output/), [2](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/Examples/iOS/SequencerTracks/AKPersonalPan/ViewController.swift)) I've seen online only show how to control an `AKSampler` with the `AKSequencer`.

Here's a simplified example from [AudioKit's GitHub page](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/Examples/iOS/SequencerTracks/AKPersonalPan/ViewController.swift):

```
// relevant class properties
var seq: AKSequencer?
var syn1 = AKSampler()

// viewDidLoad
seq = AKSequencer(filename: "seqDemo", engine: AudioKit.engine)
seq?.enableLooping()
seq!.avTracks[1].destinationAudioUnit = syn1.samplerUnit
```

**What I expected:**

Based on the above example, I'd expect to be able to do something like this:

```
var voice1 = Voice() // replaces the AKSampler

seq = AKSequencer(filename: "seqDemo", engine: AudioKit.engine)
seq.loopOn()
//seq.avTracks[0].destinationAudioUnit = voice1.oscillator.avAudioNode
seq.note = voice1.oscillator.frequency // "note" doesn't actually exist in the API
```

This doesn't do the trick obviously.

### Question:

What is the proper set-up that will allow me to control an AKOscillator with the AKSequencer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to wrap the oscillator in an midi instrument and use that. Check out the [sequencer demo](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/SequencerDemo/SequencerDemo) for an example using an fm oscillator.

Answer (score 5):

@Aurelius's answer is obviously correct but it doesn't definitively answer the question. In an effort to help the next person who has this issue I'll share my solution.

**The question is:**

How do I control an `AKOscillator` with the `AKSequencer`.

**The Answer is:**

You *can't* control it directly. As Aurelius stated, you need to wrap your oscillator in a midi instrument, which takes a little work.

- Your oscillator should be contained in a class that subclasses `AKVoice`, you can find an [example of this here](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Instruments/AKWavetableSynth.swift#L86).
- Next you'll create your wrapping "midi instrument"(aka. `AKPolyphonicInstrument`) that @Aurelius described. **This is what the sequencer has the ability to speak to!** You can see an [example of this here](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Instruments/AKWavetableSynth.swift#L13).

Now that our oscillator has the facilities to speak to the sequencer, we can implement the [MollyBChimes approach](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/Examples/iOS/MollyBChimes/AKMidiSeqDemo/ViewController.swift) like so:

At the class level create an instance of your new AKPolyphonicInstrument, for me it looks like this:

```
var osc1 = SynthVoiceInstrument(voiceCount: 4)
var sequencer = AKSequencer()
var mixer = AKMixer()
var melody: AKMIDIInstrument?
```

Then inside your set-up function or viewDidLoad you'll do the following:

```
melody = AKMIDIInstrument(instrument: osc1) 
melody?.enableMIDI(midi.midiClient, name: "melodicSound midi in")    
mixer.connect(melody!)
AudioKit.output = pumper
AudioKit.start()

sequencer.newTrack()
sequencer.setLength(seqLen)
sequencer.tracks[0].setMIDIOutput((melody?.midiIn)!)
/* 
  melody generator function just to hear some sounds
  see Melody Generator link below.
*/
genNewMelodicSequence(minor: true)

sequencer.loopEnabled = true
sequencer.setBPM(100)
sequencer.play()
```

---

[Melody Generator](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/Examples/iOS/MollyBChimes/AKMidiSeqDemo/ViewController.swift#L171)

Comment: the links you post are no longer existing